# how to update parent and subsequent children values

Tags: mysql

I am having a folders table wherein I am storing directory path, depth, parentId, title, etc.,

I have folder structure like this

```
/
/services
/products
again product has some children directories
/products/computers
and computers has some children directories
/products/computers/desktop
/products/computers/laptop etc,.
```

If want to make the `/products` as the child of `/services` it should become like this

```
/services/products
/services/products/computers
/services/products/computers/desktop
/services/products/computers/desktop etc,.
```

I have tried with this below queries I am able to update single level but not its subsequent children

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(f.id),
f.nav_depth
INTO
@ids, @depth
FROM folders f
JOIN (SELECT f1.id,
f1.parent__id 
FROM folders f1
WHERE f1.directory_path REGEXP '^/products') ta ON ta.id = f.id;

UPDATE folders
SET 
directory_path = CONCAT(parentPath,'/',title),
parent__id = 2,
nav_depth = parentnavdepth+1
WHERE id IN (@ids);
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `folders` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `directory_path` tinytext,
  `nav_depth` tinyint(3) DEFAULT '0',
  `parent__id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resource_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user__id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `UK_ltal9g0512nekqfp83u5l1huo` (`parent__id`),
  KEY `UK_cuff3r728xl6ynlp3u1dr5vt9` (`nav_depth`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[here is the link for table with data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee865/2)

Comment: Can you please include your table structure

Comment: @pala_ - I have updated my question with the table structure.

Comment: sorry, should have asked for sample data to go along with it. i know you put it up the top, but it'd be more helpful if it was in the table format

Comment: @pala_ - i have pasted the Sqlfiddle link in the question

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have been overthinking it. You can update the directory path like this:

```
update folders set directory_path = concat('/services', directory_path), nav_depth = nav_depth + 1 
  where directory_path = '/products' 
    or directory_path like '/products/%';
```

You'll have to update the parent_id for the new '/services/products' path in a second query.

I don't see how that's going to be harder than

```
update folders set parent__id = 2
  where directory_path = '/services/products';
```

[edited fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f498/1)

Comment: The biggest hurdle is to update the parent__Id, I have tried the above query it updates the directory path just fine.

Comment: surely the only parent_id that you need to update is for the path '/products'. all others are parented off that path? i just added that step - is it wrong in some way?